# How to run PHP and R on localhost and live shared servers

Tags: php, r, apache

I just started to learn R and I want to have a html form to collect user inputs and pass them into R script for rendering charts, pies, etc.

But I still don't understand how R works on browser and on PHP, despite I use the example code from this [blog](http://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/).

index.php,

```
echo "<form action='index.php' method='get'>";
echo "Number values to generate: <input type='text' name='N' />";
echo "<input type='submit' />";
echo "</form>";

if(isset($_GET['N']))
{
  $N = $_GET['N'];

  // execute R script from shell
  // this will save a plot at temp.png to the filesystem
  exec("Rscript script.R $N");

  // return image tag
  $nocache = rand();
  echo("<img src='temp.png?$nocache' />");
}
```

script.R,

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

N <- args[1]
x <- rnorm(N,0,1)

png(filename="temp.png", width=500, height=500)
hist(x, col="lightblue")
dev.off()
```

I run it on my apache localhost which I usually run my php applications, there is no result returned at all. I don't get an image just as it is shown on that blog.

So, my questions are,

1. do I have to **install** R in my localhost apache so that php can execute R?
2. what about a live shared server? how can I make R work? Do I have to install R on the live server as well? if so, my problem is - how can I install it as I definitely **don't** have the permission to install it on the shared server.

notes: I have R 3.1.3 and RStudio installed on my machine which I can run R scripts/ commands from their **consoles**. But apart from these, I **can't** run the scripts with php on my localhost.

any ideas what have I missed?

Comment: If you use Rstudio, I highly encourage you to check out R Shiny. It automates a lot of this away allowing rapid web development that uses R.

Comment: thanks. I have check it out and followed some video tutorials. but my main concern is how to host/ run r app on a live server. how can i know if a server supports r apps?

Comment: @teelou Can you please answer your question if you got any ? :)

Comment: if  rstudio and apache are installed on same server and "exec" will run like a bash command and call R !  maybe